# How to prevent removal of a child?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var o = true;
$('a#filter').click(function () {
    if(o){
        $('.heading').append('\
        <div id="fil">\
            <div class="row">\
                <div class="span12">\
                    <div class="content" style="padding-bottom:0;margin-top:0px; text-align:center; min-height:0px;background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #fafafa 0%, #e9e9e9 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #e9e9e9 100%);">\
                        <?php echo '<a href="http://njace-cc.montclair.edu/admin/users/manage.php">All</a> ' . $letters; ?>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>');

        o = false;
        $('#cls').html("▲");
    }
    else{
        $('.heading').children("#fil").remove();
        o = true;
        $('#cls').html("▼");
    }
});
```

The scenario is:

1. the user click on the link(id= filter).
2. the user gets a div contains letters from A-Z
3. if the user click on a letter then a table will be filtered.

The problem is after the GET action(clicking on a letter) the div will disappear (be removed), what I want is to still showing that div after the GET action(clicking on a letter).

I tried to trigger the click function in php tag using the following code:

```
echo '<script>$("a#filter").trigger("click");</script>';
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: $('.heading').children("#fil").remove(); removes the div. If you dont want it removed then take out that line.

Comment: Additionally, try REALLY hard not to mix languages like that. `js`, `php`, and `css` should really be in separate files that reference each other rather than mashed up.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to check if the url contains a query string (?letter=s) then keep the div otherwise don't show it??

Comment: You're right, but I have to because there are many people had been worked on the project before me

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.heading').children("#fil").remove();
```

to

```
$('.heading').children("#fil").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if(window.location.search.length){
        $("a#filter").trigger("click");
    }
});
```